# Find a file under a partially known folder path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am very new to batch files. I am trying to write a script to find this file:

```
<A>\Org\App\<B>\<C>\SQL Scripts\Miscellaneous\CRErrorFinder.exe
```

where A is any drive, B a folder name and C a folder name which should start from a known number (example: 85).

Example value of A: C:

Example value of B: TEST

Example value of C: 850-0

What I tried: I can loop over the drives to get my root search folder (something like C:\Org\App\ or D:\Org\App\ ) and then use two more loops for B and C. But is there a shorter way to achieve what I am doing here?

Comment: I would probably do something like this: `C:\>dir CRErrorFinder.exe /s /b` Once it finds the file, you have the entire path.

Comment: That would not be very efficient if I have a bunch of files and folders under C:

Comment: You can of course first go to one of the subfolders and search recursively from there. So that would be `C:\Org\App>dir CRErrorFinder.exe /s /b` But with the limited amount of information given, it is not possible to determine if there is a better method. If there is not something already leading to that file, you have to search for it, and that means a set of loops. Dir is an optimized command so it will probably be quicker than manually performing loop in loop.

Answer (score 1):

To stop after the first find try this:

```
@Echo off
Set "Drives=A: C:" 
For %%A in (%Drives%
  ) Do For /D in %%B ("%%~A\Org\App\*"
    ) Do for /D in %%C in ("%%~fB\85*"
      ) Do if exist "%%~fC\SQL Scripts\Miscellaneous\CRErrorFinder.exe" (
           Set "Find=%%~fC\SQL Scripts\Miscellaneous\CRErrorFinder.exe"
        goto :Found
      )
Echo nothing found
pause
goto :Eof
:Found
Echo Found file:%Find%
```